# Mongodb Aggregation get count of search results

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I set index for data field below, then trying to get the count of particular text search content and over all text content

My input is like this below:

```
{
_id: 14572
data: "selling bike in india"
}
{
_id: 14673
data: "sale bike in india"
}
{
_id: 14673
data: "buying cars in india"
}
```

I tired to get the count of cars, bike and total documents from collection, unfortunately not getting it,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    "Total": [
      {$match:{"$text":{$search:"india"}}},
      { "$count": "Total" },
    ],
    "bike": [
      {$match:{"$text":{$search:"bike"}}},
      { "$count": "bike" }
      ]

  { "$project": {
    "Total": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Total.Total", 0] },
    "bike": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$bikebike.Birds", 0] }
  }}
])
```

expected output like below

```
Total:3
bike:2
car:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$text` operator has some restrictions described at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html

A couple relevant to this query:

> A query can specify, at most, one $text expression.
>
> If using the $text operator in aggregation, the following restrictions also apply.
> The $match stage that includes a $text must be the first stage in the pipeline.

Since you are trying to do separate text searches for different strings, you'll need to do each one separately, like

```
db.collection.count({$text:{$search:"india"}})
db.collection.count({$text:{$search:"bike"}})
db.collection.count({$text:{$search:"car"}})
```

Comment: Thanks joe, this one does not suit me as i need to send mutiple api to get the count for the listed kewords as per above solution,                                                                                                                      I want to send one  api which must give all the information as said before

Comment: Then you can't use a text search.